# Join Through Map reduce

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

I have one collection in which student_id is the primary key:

```
test1:{student_id:"xxxxx"},
```

I have another collection in which student_id is inside array of collection:

```
class:{"class":"I",students:["student_id":"xxxx"]}
```

My problem is I want to join these two tables on the basis of student Id,

I am using map reduce and out as "merge", but it won't work.

My MR query is as follows.

```
db.runCommand({ mapreduce: "test1", 
 map : function Map() {
    emit(this._id,this);
},
 reduce : function Reduce(key, values) {
    return values;
},

 out : { merge: "testmerge"  }
 });

 db.runCommand({ mapreduce: "class", 
 map : function Map() {
    emit(this._id,this);
},
 reduce : function Reduce(key, values) {
    return values;
},

 out : { merge: "testmerge"  }
 });
```

But it inserts two rows.

Can some one guide me regarding this,I am very new to MR

As in the example I want to get the details of all student from "test1" collection,studying in class "I".

Comment: Why do you want to "join" those two tables? Usually if you need to "join" it means you need to redesign your schema. You would be better off showing a full document out of each collection, and explaining what you'd like as result.

Comment: @Derick I am preparing a thin client to mongo db which needs to collect historical data and data is distributed in multiple collections, now I have to collect all data in one sort for analysis, without doing multiple read.

Comment: Add it to the question, not in comments please...

Comment: I edited the question.As in the example I want to get the details of all student from "test1" collection,studying in class "I".

Comment: You should consider a schema redesign rather than trying to force MongoDb to do something it wasn't designed to do. MapReduce in MongoDb, unlike some other NoSql DBs, isn't automatically updated.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement seems to be:

> As in the example I want to get the details of all student from "test1" collection,studying in class "I".

In order to do that, store which classes a student is in with the student:

```
{
    student_id: "xxxxx",
    classes: ["I"],
},
```

Then you can just ask for all the students information with:

```
db.students.find( { classes: "I" } );
```

Without any need for slow and complex map reduce jobs. In general, you should avoid Map/Reduce as it can't make use of indexes and can not run concurrently. You also need to understand that in MongoDB operations are only done on **one** collection. There is no such thing as a join, and trying to emulate this with Map/Reduce is a bad idea. At least you can just do it with two queries:

```
// find all students in class "I":
ids = []; 
db.classes.find( { class: "I" } ).forEach(function(e) { ids.push( e.student_id ) ; } );
// then with the result, find all of those students information:
db.students.find( { student_id: { $in: ids } } );
```

But I would strongly recommend you redesign your schema and store the classes with each student. As a general hint, in MongoDB you would store the relation between documents on the **other** side as compared to a relational database.

Comment: you are handling in the mongo shell, so I am using Mongo Driver, So I have to handle it in my application, and do two read,something I want to avoid.

Comment: Like I said, then you will have to redesign your schema. Do note that two reads is going to be a hell-of-a-lot faster than using Map/Reduce. Even though this is on the shell, I'm sure you understand what it does and rewrite it to Java—your question was all in Javascript as well anyway.